# Get value from a TextInput component in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Dynamically generate a TextInput when you press a button but I can’t get the value that the user digits,try to use states but I can’t because it’s not with the other general textInputs but it’s imported as Field.

try to create a state in the component file and move it to the general view and print it to see if it works and not...is there any way to bring this state?

general view:

```
    import Campo from './campoInput';
  
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state={
  Cbusto:"",
  Ccintura:"",
  Ccadera:"",
  valueArray: []
};
this.addNewEle = false;

}

  agregarCampo=()=>{
  this.addNewEle = true;
  const newlyAddedValue = { text: 'prueba'};

  this.setState({
  
    valueArray: [...this.state.valueArray, newlyAddedValue]
  });
}
render(){
return(

------Here are the normal textInput-----

     <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 4 }}>
        {this.state.valueArray.map((ele) => {
          return <Campo item={ele} />;
        })}
      </View>

      <View style={styles.flex}>
        <View style={styles.ButtonAdd}>
          <Button
            title="Add input"
            color="#B13682"
            onPress={this.agregarCampo}
          ></Button>
        </View>

)
}
```

Component:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
     this.state={
    info:""
    }; 
    }

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>pruba:{this.props.item.text}</Text>
            <View style={styles.input}>
            <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({info:text})}></TextInput>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can be solved by adding the onChangeText event to the Field component in the overview and in the same way in the TextInput of the component being imported, using props status

General view:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 4 }}>
        {this.state.valueArray.map((ele) => {
          return <Campo item={ele}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ info: text })}
          />;
        })}
 </View>
```

Component

```
 <View>
         <Text>pruba:{this.props.item.text}</Text>
         <View style={styles.input}>
         <TextInput onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}></TextInput>
         </View>
 </View>
```